# How can i send a string from one device to another via NFC?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I want to send a string to another device via NFC .
I could not find any relevant information on how to send and how to receive data via NFC.
I could not find any info on android official documentation and for file transfer document says use bluetooth.
Please help me.

Comment: does this help https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#java

Comment: Not easy but could use  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce for sending device to emulate a Tag and then standard Tag reading for receiving device. Not tried this but https://github.com/hakonschia/nfc-card-emulator

Comment: Do you have found any good resources or anything else on this? @RR_Pradhan

Comment: No. My requirement changed so i didn't need anymore. But check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394355/how-can-i-send-a-text-string-to-another-device-via-nfc